# Bug Report: I edited my question and the existing answers disappeared

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers

[Where does Python's pydoc help function get its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787056/where-does-pythons-pydoc-help-function-get-its-content-from)

There were two answers when I edited it and right after the edit they were gone. Seems unlikely that they both deleted their answers just as I made the edit.

Comment: hmm, mods, check whether those answers are deleted or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the edits you made to the question changed it enough that the answers were no longer valid.  Both of the answers were deleted by their respective authors right after an edit that you made.

Comment: I'm aware that high rep users can see deleted answers, what about letting the question owner see them as well?

Comment: No. Deleted answers are deleted for a reason. Often it's because they are not correct anymore, but I'm sure sometimes people want their answer to stay invisible.